# Apply filters to an image, loaded from json

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need some help.

I have a String JSON, that contains the structure of an image object of FabricJS, than contains filters.

I want to apply these filters, when I load the image in the canvas.

How i can do this?

```
"1":
    {
        "type": "image",
        "originX": "left",
        "originY": "top",
        "lockMovementX": false,
        "lockMovementY": false,
        "lockScalingX": false,
        "lockScalingY": false,
        "lockRotation": false,
        "lockUniScaling": false,
        "lockScalingFlip": false,
        "left": 193.13,
        "top": 70.87,
        "width": 718,
        "height": 647,
        "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeDashArray": null,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
        "scaleX": 0.17,
        "scaleY": 0.17,
        "angle": 0,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "shadow": null,
        "visible": true,
        "clipTo": null,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "transformMatrix": null,
        "src": "cuadradito.png",
        "filters": [
            {
                "type": "Invert"
            }
        ],
        "crossOrigin": "",
        "alignX": "none",
        "alignY": "none",
        "meetOrSlice": "meet"
    }
```

The code of the top, is the object of the image.
This code is loaded from a BD, with a ajax request.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes, in a few hours please, thanks

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the delay,
What I want is, given a json, apply filters it contains an image using ApplyFilters () function. How can I do that?:
https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/swm748sp/

Comment: So you have a json which is actually the result of export canvas. Why are manually adding items instead of using loadFromJSON method?

Comment: These JSON is a variable, that only contain the objects in fabricjs. In muy applycation we not serialize cavas, serialize the variable...

Comment: Sloved, i changed the method to load the canvas. Thanks Jayadratha Mondal

Comment: Happy to hear that it solved. Welcome @Pedro Jose